# Packaging cloud project in Visual Studio : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets : The directory is not empty

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, azure-cloud-services

I have an ASP.NET project destined for an Azure web role cloud service. We already had different branches in TFS targeting different environments and cloud services and have been working fine all along. Today we are switching over to Git for our version control, and I have re-defining the branches since its branching concept differs from traditional folder models like TFVC or SVN.

Everything was going fine - create new branch, apply environment-specific config, done - until the last branch. For some reason, triggering package action on this branch's cloud service project gets a "The directory is not empty" error.

I have removed all read-only attributes to the folders and files (something which solved the previous branch) but does not appear to be the case here.

```
7>Target "CorePublish" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" from project "E:\projects\Auth\CloudDeployment\cloudservice\cloudservice.ccproj" (target "Publish" depends on it):
7>  Task "Message"
7>      CorePublish: PackageWebRole = True
7>  Task "Message"
7>      Publishing starting...
7>  Task "Message"
7>      RolePlugins       is 
7>  Task "Message"
7>      Importedmodules is 
7>  Task "Message"
7>      Publishing to 'bin\Release\app.publish\'
7>  Task "MakeDir"
7>      Creating directory "bin\Release\app.publish\".
7>  Task "Message"
7>      TargetServiceDefinition is bin\Release\ServiceDefinition.csdef
7>  Task "Message"
7>      TargetServiceConfiguration is bin\Release\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
7>  Task "Message"
7>      Roles is E:\projects\Auth\CloudDeployment\cloudservice\obj\Release\cloudservice\
7>  Task "CSPack"
7>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2880,5): error : The directory is not empty.
```

What could affect the Windows Azure MSBuild process in this way?

UPDATE

Ok when I pull the branch out to another computer, it packages just fine there. Something is amiss with this computer of mine. I wonder what...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [from others' experiences](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/eada815e-7177-469a-9e2d-789fb0828e32/azure-publish-error-the-directory-is-not-empty?forum=windowsazuremanagement) real-time anti-virus mechanisms can somehow interfere with the Windows Azure MSBuild process. Disabling my workstation's anti-virus real-time protection seems to get around the problem.